# PHP error trying to get AWS s3 object from server while code works fine locally

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get a specific file from an s3 bucket. Essentially I'm trying to make sure a file has been uploaded before I remove it from my server. I've been able to upload files using the same credentials with no issue. And I have been able to run the code locally from the browser and command line. But on my aws server I am get this error:

```
Class 'SimpleXMLElement' not found in ../vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Api/Parser/PayloadParserTrait.php on line 44
```

I've gotten this error before while writing the code to upload files. One time it was because I had the wrong secret, the other was due to file sizes. So I don't think this error is narrowing down my issue. I believe it is preventing the script from outputting the actual error since it's been the same for multiple issues.

Before adding:

```
"scheme" => "http"
```

to my S3Client object I was getting an ssl certification error locally:

```
Error executing "PutObject" on "{s3 url}"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

With adding that line it works locally through the command line but still not on my aws server. I believe the issue has a lot more to do with the error that I was receiving locally rather than the simplexml error that is output. Here's my code (I'm aware the "scheme" line is commented out):

```
        $s3 = new S3Client([
            "version" => "latest",
            "region"  => "us-east-2",
            // "scheme" => "http",
            "credentials" => [
                "key"    => "$key",
                "secret" => "$secret"
            ]
        ]);

        try {
            // Retrieve data.
            $objects = $s3->getIterator("ListObjects", array(
                "Bucket" => $bucket,
                "Prefix" => "$site$file"
            ));

            echo "Searching through s3 bucket...\n";

            foreach ($objects as $object) {
                if($object["Key"] === "$site$file") {
                    echo "Matching event found in s3 bucket, proceeding with deletion\n";
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;

        } catch (S3Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
            return $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
        }
```

Installing simplexml will not fix my issue as I tried going down that rabbit hole the last time this error popped up. Just wondering if anyone may have encountered anything similar and have something for me to try. Or maybe suggestions on better error handling to try and get a different output other than this simplexml line. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm using php 5.6 and apache on an ubuntu 16.04 server.

Comment: You need exactly what you say it won't resolve the issue. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml`

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you know this? I stated my previous 2 issues with this error had nothing to do with installing xml so why would this case be different? Especially when the upload works just fine. Also if you've tried to install php5.6-xml recently on ubuntu 16.04 you'd know that no longer works. Maybe this will be an easy fix once I can upgrade, but for now I need to work with what I have.

Comment: compare local ```php -m``` to your server ```php -m```, you will probably see xml in there locally. @Riz is likely correct

Comment: I don't disagree that it would probably fix my issue. However I don't have the ability to install it currently. In my question I was asking for a suggestion that wasn't installing xml as it ended up not being necessary in my previous 2 issues that showed the same error. It could likely be that simplexml is required just to display the proper error since I was getting a descriptive error locally and not on the server. I will edit this to put emphasis on the local error rather than the simplexml error.